# how to recognize loing success or not in webmatrix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

I'm very new in `webmatrix` I have write code for login page but i don't have any idea is my login success or not? In short how can i switch next page if login success here is my code

```
    @{
    var db=Database.Open("TestData");
    var UserName=Request.Form["UserName"];
    var Password=Request.Form["Password"];
    var error=false;


    if (IsPost){

   var loginquery="SELECT * FROM Test_tb where UserName=@0 and Password=@1";
   db.Execute(loginquery,UserName,Password);

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace

```
db.Execute(loginquery,UserName,Password);
```

with

```
var userData = db.QuerySingle(loginquery,UserName,Password);
```

and test if userData is null (login unsuccessfull) or not null (login successfull)

```
if (userData == null) {
    // login unsuccessfull
} else {
    // login successfull
}
```

Nevertheless, consider that there are better ways to implement security in your WebMatrix site.

WebMatrix includes the WebSecurity helper with login and logout methods and a Starter Site template useful to start a site with registering and login functions. This is a tutorial on the use of the template: [Adding Security and Membership to an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var loginquery="SELECT Count(*) FROM Test_tb where UserName=@0 and Password=@1";
var success = (int)db.QueryValue(loginquery,UserName,Password);
```

If success is 0 then login is not successful.